# Compose HTTP(S) Requests with Telerik Fiddler Classic using an authorization token

Tags: telerik, fiddler

I am trying to know how to send a GET request url using an authorization token in the header similar as below:

> Authorization: Token token="here my personal token"

What have I tried:

In the composer, I have selected GET verb and I have indicated my url.
In the box under URL I have specified the headers, one line by line, and the last one I have specified is the above indicated.

When I click on Execute button I get HTTP 502 error message.

In Postman, another alternative to Fiddler Classic, I specify the authorization token in the header and it works ok.

So what am I doing wrong in Telerik Fiddler Classic?

**Postman configuration**

Postman Params tab:
[image]

Postman Authorization tab:
[image]

Postman Headers tab:
[image]

Postman 7 hidden header entries:
These hidden entries are postman-specific. I have not introduced them manually. Only first two are checked (enabled), the rest are unchecked (disabled). In case of first hidden header "Cookie", if I remove it and send the request, it is added automatically by Postman again.

[image]

And the same in Telerik Fiddler Classic, same request with same params and headers does not work. See below screenshot.

**Telerik Fiddler Classic configuration**
[image]

**UPDATE 2021/07/28**:
Finally I have solved by changing TLS from 1.0 to 1.2.

Below are the steps I have followed in Fiddler Classic:

1. Tools/Options/HTTPS
2. Check "Decrypt HTTP traffic"
3. Install fiddler certificate
4. Change TLS1.0 to TLS1.2 in protocols

[image]

After doing that, I execute the request and it works perfectly.
Also, I do not know why but once I have done above steps if I go again to Tools/Options/HTTPS and uncheck "Decrypt HTTP traffic" option, the request continue working correctly.

Comment: I don't think that the Authorization header is the problem, most likely you modified something else that causes the request to fail. This might be server specific or the request in defect in general. Inspect the sent request in Fiddler request/response list and check if it looks OK.

Comment: @Robert I execute the request from the same server and the request is exactly the same in both cases. In Postman it works, but not in Fiddler Classic. So it is not a server specific problem. This is something wrong with fiddler classic, maybe I do not know how to specify the header parameters.

Comment: @Robert I have update my post with screenshots. Same request with same params and headers. Results -> Postman works and Telerik Fiddler Classic does not work. This request using Postman and Fiddler Classic is in the same server machine. So it is not a server-specific problem. Something in Fiddler Classic is wrong but I do not know what, well from the http 502 error message it seems like authorization token in Fiddler is not being recognized. I wonder if maybe in Fiddler authorization token must be encoded to Base64 using TextWizard tool?

Comment: If I interpret the Postman screenshot correct there are 7 more header entries that are hidden (in total 12 header entries). May be you should transfer them to Fiddler as well...

Comment: @Robert Yes, 7 hidden header entries but those entries are not related to the request instead they are postman-specific headers. Furthermore only the two first are checked (enabled), the rest are unchecked (disabled). See my last update, I have put a screenshot. I haven't introduced manually those 7 hidden header entries. I think they are related to postman how it manage the request.

Comment: Just configure Postman to use Fiddler as proxy and you will get the correct request.

Comment: @Robert Postman works perfectly, request is performed correctly. The problem is from Fiddler. When I try to send the same request from Fiddler, I get the error. 
So why configure Postman to use Fiddler as a proxy if with Postman I already get the correct request? What I need to know is how to configure Fiddler to get the correct request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235396/discussion-between-robert-and-rodri).

Comment: @Robert Finally I have solved it. See my update 2021/07/28. I have go to "Tools/Options/HTTPS" and then I have enabled "Decrypt HTTPS traffic", install a  fiddler certificate and change TLS1.0 to TLS1.2 in protocols. After that request works perfectly. Once it is working if I go again to "Tools/Options/HTTPS" and disable "Decrypt HTTPS traffic", request continue working.

Comment: So effectively you have not understand why your request in Fiddler was not working. As I said I assume it was a typo, may be a tab instead of a space or something like that. I was hoping you compare your request and the postman request to finally get the cause of your question.